# Extract Value from JSON string in EXCEL

Tags: json, excel, excel-formula

I have hundreds of single line JSON strings and I am trying to extract the value related to ActiveServices.

However, not all the cells start the same, some strings start like this:

[{"id":"ActiveServices","type":"count","value":"1"},{"id":"HasActiveService","type":"boolean","value":"true"}]

and others are like this:

[{"id":"HasActiveService","type":"boolean","value":"true"},{"id":"ActiveServices","type":"count","value":"16"}]

and like this:

[{"id":"HasActiveIssue","type":"boolean","value":"true"},{"id":"HasActiveNewIssue","type":"boolean","value":"true"},{"id":"ActiveLowIssues","type":"count","value":"1"},{"id":"ActiveServices","type":"count","value":"1"},{"id":"HasActiveService","type":"boolean","value":"true"},{"id":"ActiveNewIssues","type":"count","value":"1"},{"id":"ActiveIssues","type":"count","value":"1"},{"id":"HasActiveLowIssue","type":"boolean","value":"true"}]

My current formula only works for the 1st and 3rd JSON string structures.

This is my current formula:

```
=TRIM(MID(P4,FIND("value", P4, FIND(""""&Q4&"""", P4))+8,SEARCH(",",P4,FIND("value", P4, FIND(""""&Q4&"""", P4)))-FIND("value", P4, FIND(""""&Q4&"""", P4))-10))
```

P4 has my JSON string, Q4 has the word I am finding "ActiveServices"

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Which Excel version do you have?

Comment: Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2202 Build 16.0.14931.20806) 64-bit

Answer (score 3):

There are shorter ways of doing this I'm sure, but I'm thinking it would be rather neat to first split a JSON in an actual array, then filter out the data needed:

```
=LET(a,TEXTSPLIT(P4,{""":""",""","""},{"[{""","""},{""","""}]"},1),FILTER(TAKE(a,,-1),INDEX(a,,2)=Q4))
```

The idea here is to first `TEXTSPLIT()` the JSON string into an array of values, so:

`[{"id":"ActiveServices","type":"count","value":"1"},{"id":"HasActiveService","type":"boolean","value":"true"}]`

Becomes:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | ActiveServices | type | count | value | 1 |
| id | HasActiveService | type | boolean | value | true |

The array is saved in a variable called `a` which we then `FILTER()` to `TAKE()` the last element (column) which represents the values we are after and test the 2nd element (`INDEX(a,,2)`) which represents the ID we are after.